# Data not showing from web api to React in front-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net

I'm trying to fetch data from webapi to display in react js tables, everything seems to work fine only text is not being displayed in these table the look empty[!
What might be the problem here, because I can't figure it out for days.

[Image of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq9wy.png)

[this is the error Im getting in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2e96.png)

This is my Department.js file

````
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { ModalBody, ModalTitle } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { variables } from './variables';

export class Department extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            departments:[],
            modalTitle:"",
            DepartmentName:"",
            DepartmentId:0,

            DepartmentIdFilter:"",
            DepartmentNameFilter:"",
            departmentsWithoutFilter:[]
        }
    }

    FilterFn(){
        var DepartmentIdFilter=this.state.DepartmentIdFilter;
        var DepartmentNameFilter = this.state.DepartmentNameFilter;

        var filteredData=this.state.departmentsWithoutFilter.filter(
            function(el){
                return el.DepartmentId.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                    DepartmentIdFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                )&&
                el.DepartmentName.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                    DepartmentNameFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                )
            }
        );

        this.setState({departments:filteredData});

    }

    sortResult(prop,asc){
        var sortedData=this.state.departmentsWithoutFilter.sort(function(a,b){
            if(asc){
                return (a[prop]>b[prop])?1:((a[prop]<b[prop])?-1:0);
            }
            else{
                return (b[prop]>a[prop])?1:((b[prop]<a[prop])?-1:0);
            }
        });

        this.setState({departments:sortedData});
    }

    changeDepartmentIdFilter = (e)=>{
        this.state.DepartmentIdFilter=e.target.value;
        this.FilterFn();
    }
    changeDepartmentNameFilter = (e)=>{
        this.state.DepartmentNameFilter=e.target.value;
        this.FilterFn();
    }

    refreshList(){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+'departments')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({departments:data,departmentsWithoutFilter:data});
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshList();
    }
    
    changeDepartmentName =(e)=>{
        this.setState({DepartmentName:e.target.value});
    }

    addClick(){
        this.setState({
            modalTitle:"Add Department",
            DepartmentId:0,
            DepartmentName:""
        });
    }
    editClick(dep){
        this.setState({
            modalTitle:"Edit Department",
            DepartmentId:dep.DepartmentId,
            DepartmentName:dep.DepartmentName
        });
    }

    createClick(){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+'departments',{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                DepartmentName:this.state.DepartmentName
            })
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then((result)=>{
            alert(result);
            this.refreshList();
        },(error)=>{
            alert('Failed');
        })
    }


    updateClick(){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+'departments',{
            method:'PUT',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                DepartmentId:this.state.DepartmentId,
                DepartmentName:this.state.DepartmentName
            })
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then((result)=>{
            alert(result);
            this.refreshList();
        },(error)=>{
            alert('Failed');
        })
    }

    deleteClick(id){
        if(window.confirm('Are you sure?')){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+'departments/'+ id,{
            mode:'no-cors',
            method:'DELETE',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then((result)=>{
            alert(result);
            this.refreshList();
        },(error)=>{
            alert('Failed');
        })
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {
            departments,
            modalTitle,
            DepartmentId,
            DepartmentName
        }=this.state;

        return(
            
<div>

    <button type="button"
    className="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
    onClick={()=>this.addClick()}>
        Add Department
    </button>
    <table className="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr key={Department.id}>
        
        <th>
            <div className="d-flex flex-row">

            
            <input className="form-control m-2"
            onChange={this.changeDepartmentIdFilter}
            placeholder="Filter"/>
            
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light"
            onClick={()=>this.sortResult('DepartmentId',true)}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-arrow-down-square-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2zm6.5 4.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 10.293V4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                </svg>
            </button>

            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light"
            onClick={()=>this.sortResult('DepartmentId',false)}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-arrow-up-square-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M2 16a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2zm6.5-4.5V5.707l2.146 2.147a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-3 3a.5.5 0 1 0 .708.708L7.5 5.707V11.5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0z"/>
                </svg>
            </button>

            </div>
            DepartmentId
        </th>
        <th>
        <div className="d-flex flex-row">
        <input className="form-control m-2"
            onChange={this.changeDepartmentNameFilter}
            placeholder="Filter"/>

            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light"
            onClick={()=>this.sortResult('DepartmentName',true)}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-arrow-down-square-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2zm6.5 4.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 10.293V4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                </svg>
            </button>

            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light"
            onClick={()=>this.sortResult('DepartmentName',false)}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-arrow-up-square-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M2 16a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2zm6.5-4.5V5.707l2.146 2.147a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-3 3a.5.5 0 1 0 .708.708L7.5 5.707V11.5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0z"/>
                </svg>
            </button>
            </div>
            DepartmentName
      
        </th>
        <th>
            Options
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {departments.map(dep=>
            <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
                <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                <td>
                <button type="button"
                className="btn btn-light mr-1"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
                onClick={()=>this.editClick(dep)}>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
                    <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>

                <button type="button"
                className="btn btn-light mr-1"
                onClick={()=>this.deleteClick(dep.DepartmentId)}>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>

                </td>
            </tr>
            )}
    </tbody>
    </table>

<div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
<div className="modal-content">
   <div className="modal-header">
       <h5 className="modal-title">{modalTitle}</h5>
       <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
       ></button>
   </div>

   <div className="modal-body">
       <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <span className="input-group-text">DepartmentName</span>
        <input type="text" className="form-control"
        value={DepartmentName}
        onChange={this.changeDepartmentName}/>
       </div>

        {DepartmentId===0?
        <button type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary float-start"
        onClick={()=>this.createClick()}
        >Create</button>
        :null}

        {DepartmentId!==0?
        <button type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary float-start"
        onClick={()=>this.updateClick()}
        >Update</button>
        :null}

   </div>

</div>
</div> 
</div>


</div>
        )
    }
}```

This is my Program.cs 

    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using WebApp.Data;
    
    var myAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
    
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    });
    
    //Enable CORS
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: myAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
            });
    });
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
    app.UseCors(myAllowSpecificOrigins);
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllers();
    
    app.Run();


What might be the problem here, because I can't figure it out for days.
Does anyone had the same issue? 
It looks like I have done something wrong in react js file
````

Comment: Maybe try the solution in this post here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js

Comment: Try a quick log to see the response from server : `<tbody>{console.log(departments)}...`. it seems that your server response is not like `[{DepartmentName: 'd1'}, ...]`. (you can also see the response from server in inspector `netwrk` tab)

Comment: Also your console error says that in `<tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>`, `dep.DepartmentId` is not a unique id for each item (probably because it's undefined or empty string in every item.).

Comment: I fixed this now, the error in console has gone now but still the same problem the data are not displaying